# How to show category to user

Tags: python, html, django

I practice coding with html and django and I have a project "Movie Reviews" and I have some question.

how to show category for user who often click that category?

e.g 
You often like to chose Romantic category.Website should show romantic category to you when you come to this website again.(already login)

sorry for my English.I'm beginner for English and Coding.

Thankyou

Comment: What models do you have right now to specify the category?

Comment: I use models in django when I runserver and go to admin page.It's  a models right? I don't know I watched on youtube sorry I'm very newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very wide, but this should help you; I guess you already have a `Category` and a `Movie` model, right?

Those two are probably related trough a one-to-many relationship. Here you should do something similar, but you'll need a [many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

The simplest way of doing it would be to create a new model, for example 'CategoryVisited', with 3 fields: user_id, category_id, and count.

Then, each time a user visits a category, you'll either create a new CategoryVisited or get the existing one matching the current user_id and category_id, and increment the 'count' field.

At last, to retrieve the preferred category of a user, you'll have to write a simple 'max' request to get the category_id with the max count for the current user.

Comment: I'll try it.thank you very much ><